# Eigen::Matrix<double,1,3> return type function in a struct type function

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to write a function which is of `struct` type, but it returns `eigen::matrix` type vector (so to say...)

For example:

```
struct foo (){ double a,b,c; };  
foo FOO(){  
    typedef eigen::Matrix<double,1,3> foofoo;
    foo f;
    // .....                 // some expressions that generate some numerical values
    f.a; f.b;f.c;         // numerical values are put in here
    foofoo<<f.a, f.b,f.c; // assigned to the eigen::matrix
    return foofoo;        // attempt to return eigen::matrix type vector
}
```

I am unsure about where to declare the `eigen::matrix` type vector. Should it be inside the function or in the `struct` or should it be a separate `struct` of `eigen::matrix` type or any other way is preferred.

Comment: A function cannot be of struct type... Here, your function return a `foo`, not even a `foofoo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "a function of struct type", and your struct declaration syntax is really weird. You seem to be confusing types with objects.

Here's what I think you need, simply a function that returns an instance of your `eigen::Matrix` specialisation (which you've named `foofoo` via a type alias):

```
struct foo
{
   double a, b, c;
};

using foofoo = eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 3>;

foofoo FOO()
{
   foofoo result;

   foo f;
   // ... populate members of f ...
   result << f.a, f.b, f.c;

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how you populate an Eigen object, they overloaded the comma operator.

Comment: As an aside, it would be better to use clearer names, even for example purposes. `foo`, `FOO` and `foofoo` don't stand out next to each other.

Comment: thanks for the corrections and the answer i think this is what i needed. but i want to just ask what's the difference between using  typedef eigen::Matrix<double,1,3> foofoo; or using foofoo = eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 3>;

Comment: @as50075 In this case nothing, but the latter is new C++11 syntax and is "better" in general (you can research why)